# Fax barcode recognition software to integrate in a c# application

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

My application is preparing a cover-sheet for submitting documents by fax. I identify the batch by printing a [Code39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39) on it.

The incoming faxes are received as tif files and my small c# service is polling for new faxes and calling a decoding function.

Currently I use a Win32 dll to recognize the barcode ([QSbar39](http://www.qsbarcode.de/)) and I am facing some problems with it - timeouts, hangs, errors etc. which are painful to handle.

I'd prefer the have some free .Net component or an open source class to integrate.

Whould you take a different approach? What tool do you use?

Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, how did you produce the code39 barcode?

Comment: Just use the appropiate font and enclose your string with an asterix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BarBara](http://sourceforge.net/projects/barbara/) is an open source barcode recognition library.  It certainly isn't perfect, but I have gotten it to work (if I remember it needed some twiddling to get it to compile in VS2008) pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this java libarary with good results, and have gotten it to compile in .Net with minimal effort.  It's been around for a while and works pretty well.  It had some minor issues with EAN codes, but that has probably been resolved now.

http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is anything available free or open source, but [VintaSoftBarcode.NET Library](http://www.vintasoft.com/vsbarcode-dotnet-index.html) is pretty cheap and did the job for me on a recent project.